# MySQL default value as other field's value

Tags: mysql, dynamic, default

Can I, and, if I can, how can I set the default value of a field in a MySQL table to the value of another field?

Thing is: I have data, and each data object has its ID in the table. But, I would like the possibility to rearrange the data, changing their sorting index, without altering their ID. Thus, the field `sort_num` should by default be set to the value given to the auto-incremented indexed field `ID`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql set field default value to other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384429/mysql-set-field-default-value-to-other-column)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two possible solutions for this:

**1. Possibility:**

You use a function to simply ignore `sort_num` if it is not set:

```
`SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY coalesce(sort_num, id)`
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value, therefore you would insert values for `sort_num` if you really need to reorder items.

**2. Possibility:**

You write a trigger, which automatically sets the value if it is not set in the insert statement:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER sort_num_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE auto_inc INT;
    IF (NEW.sort_num  is null) THEN
         -- determine next auto_increment value
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO auto_inc FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable';
        -- and set the sort value to the same as the PK
        SET NEW.sort_num = auto_inc;
    END IF;
END
//
```

(inspired by [this comment](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2006/03/mysql-triggers-accessing-value-of-auto.html#c4146641749476768148))

However, this might run into parallelization issues (multiple queries inserting at the same time)

Answer (score 3):

Its a bad idea to have an auto-increment column rearranged, hence better idea would be

Add a column sort_num to the table

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD sort_num column-definition; (column definition same as ID)

UPDATE data SET sort_num = ID
```

Now play with sort_num column as it has no effect on column ID

Comment: well, I never intended to have the auto-increment column rearranged, the sort_num just needed the other's value as default in order for the sort_num column to be rearranged and not mess with the indices and the auto increments

Comment: Well you could use the above suggested method or deal with this on the server side. Like doing insert, getting last_insert_key and then update table data set sort_num = id where id = last_insert_key