# MySQL: set field default value to other column

Tags: mysql, default, default-value

How to set default value for a field to other column in MySQL?

I have done it in Oracle with virtual field, but I do not know how to do it in MySQL.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE TSM_TRANSACTION_TBL
(
  TRANS_ID     INT primary key auto_increment,
  LOCATION_ID  INT,
  TRANS_DATE   DATE,
  RESOURCE_ID  INT,
  TS_ID        INT,
  MAX_VALUE    INT,
  BOOKED_UNITS INT default 0,
  REMAINING    INT default MAX_VALUE - BOOKED_UNITS,
  BOOKED       INT not null,
  USER_ID      INT,
  TRANS_TIME   TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377977/mysql-default-value-as-other-fields-value

Answer (score 31):

As documented under [Data Type Default Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The `DEFAULT value` clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) or [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date). The exception is that you can specify [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) as the default for a [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) column. See [Section 11.3.5, “Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP`”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Instead, you can define an insertion trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE INSERT ON TSM_TRANSACTION_TBL FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.REMAINING IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.REMAINING := NEW.MAX_VALUE - NEW.BOOKED_UNITS;
  END IF;;
```

Comment: I used your code but it told me that  i can not use new with after insert and i changed it to before and it is working perfectly

Comment: For those check this recently, MySQL allows functions now for the DEFAULT clause https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: You may need to specify delimeters here. If you do add this before:
DELIMITER $$

And this after:
$$

That allows mysql to interpret the code inbetween as a single statement

Answer (score 20):

The 'NEW' is unacceptable for AFTER insert triggers. You should do the 'field update' by a BEFORE insert trigger. So,

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE INSERT ON TSM_TRANSACTION_TBL FOR EACH ROW
    IF NEW.REMAINING IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.REMAINING := NEW.MAX_VALUE - NEW.BOOKED_UNITS;
    END IF;;
```

Comment: I fix @eggyal's answer

Answer (score 10):

As of [MySQL 8.0.13](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit), you can reference another column as the default value of a column.

> An expression default value for one column can refer to other table columns, with the exception that references to generated columns or columns with expression default values must be to columns that occur earlier in the table definition. That is, expression default values cannot contain forward references to generated columns or columns with expression default values.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  name_url varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT (`name`),

  created datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (UTC_TIMESTAMP()),
  modified datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (UTC_TIMESTAMP()),

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

After srearching.. i found some solutions.

**first solution: using default**

```
REMAINING    INT default (MAX_VALUE - BOOKED_UNITS)
```

this solution will only give value if you didn't give a value when insert.

**second solution: using Trigger**

[SQL auto-create a value column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802921/sql-auto-create-a-value-column)

**third solution: using GENERATED ALWAYS AS**

number1 INT,
number2 INT,
result INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS(number2 - number1),

this solution will always fill it for you after insert