# mysql puting 2 column with same value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make 2 columns have the same value, but the procedures saved are already made and I'm trying to avoid change, then I wonder if it is possible that the mysql do default, the idea would be that when you save a value for `ID_Student` the same value is stored in `ID`, because my method only adds value to `ID_Student`, and `ID` is a null (now is a auto_increment)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql set field default value to other column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384429/mysql-set-field-default-value-to-other-column)

Answer (score 1):

I think your only options are to add a trigger on the table (that fires on insert/update) or to update the procedure that does the initial insert.

Comment: 2 thing, first the trigger should be executed for each insert, right? This execution will be manual or mysql do ?, the second, it will consume more resources?

Comment: yes, after the insert.  It will be automatic after you define the trigger on the table.  It will consume unoticibly small resources only on the insert event (as would doing it in the stored procedure).  EG: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html