# SQL auto-create a value column

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table in a SQL Server database with columns `E-mail`, `Mobile Number`, `AuthCode`, `UserID`.

When I add a new user, the `AuthCode` column should be filled with a value like this:

```
UserID+Mobile Number.
```

Like this: if new user has a mobile number of `05518602015` and UserID (Autoincrement) of `2`, then the `AuthCode` column should automatically be filled with `205518602015`.

How can I do this ? I'm new to SQL Server

SOLVED : Using Triggers.

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: Maybe i can do with another platform like java classes when add new user  create new authcode and write it to auth code column

Comment: Use triggers on INSERT, UPDATE.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha   How can i use them ? Must I write a query to where ?  Please explain a bit im newbie

Comment: Thank you i m trying to fix with triggers now

Comment: @OzanManav my pleasure, if any of the answers helps you, fell free to accept/upvote it, it is a great way to say "thanks" here! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) for that purpose:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername  
ON dbo.YourTableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Y
    SET AuthCode = CAST(i.UserID AS NVARCHAR(10)) + CAST(i.[Mobile Number] AS NVARCHAR(20))
    FROM YourTableName Y
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON Y.someID = i.someID
END
```

It will update column you need after insert/update operation on rows which was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple computed column?

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
        UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Email NVARCHAR(50), 
        MobileNumber NVARCHAR(100), 
        AuthCode AS CAST(UserID AS NVARCHAR(10)) + MobileNumber
        )


INSERT INTO #Test(Email, MobileNumber) VALUES (N'blah@somewhere.com', N'0123456790')

SELECT * FROM #Test

UserID      Email                 MobileNumber     AuthCode
----------- --------------------- ---------------- ----------------
1           blah@somewhere.com    0123456790       10123456790

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: That's a nice solution but I would prefer using trigger, and store the data right in the table without calculation. A computed column with the formula is being calculated every time you try to access it - just be aware of that.

Comment: @gofr1 True, however if the column is deterministic then you can mark it `PERSISTED` and the engine will store the computed value during insert.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.City 
SET Auth = CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CityId), CityName)
```

Above query will set data as you want you can use the condition to update particular data

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it in two steps, add the user first and then update the AuthCode,

```
CREATE TABLE #Users (
        UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Email VARCHAR(100), 
        MobileNumber VARCHAR(20), 
        AuthCode VARCHAR(50)
        )

DECLARE @NewUserID      INT,
        @Email          VARCHAR(100),
        @MobileNumber   VARCHAR(20),
        @AuthCode       VARCHAR(50)

SELECT  @Email = 'usertestmail@gmail.com'
        ,@MobileNumber = '05518602015'

-- Add new user
INSERT INTO #Users(Email, MobileNumber)
VALUES (@Email, @MobileNumber)

SET @NewUserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  -- this will give the Identity of the newly added row

SET @AuthCode = CAST(@NewUserID AS VARCHAR(20)) + @MobileNumber

--SELECT @AuthCode

-- update the Auth code
UPDATE u
SET AuthCode = @AuthCode
FROM #Users u
WHERE u.UserID = @NewUserID

SELECT * FROM #Users
```

### OUTPUT

```
UserID      Email                     MobileNumber   AuthCode     
----------- ------------------------- -------------- -------------
1           usertestmail@gmail.com    05518602015    105518602015
```

Comment: **No**: you don't need to do this in two steps - see the answer about a **trigger** which allows you to do this automatically, in a single step.

Comment: I would prefer it at code side rather going for the trigger solution! with trigger too, it is done in two steps!