# Is it possible to set the standard value of a column to the value of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the standard value of column B to be the value of Column A in the same row until it is changed through a user triggered UPDATE. Is that possible?

I'm using Mysql 8 and phpmyadmin, if that matters.

Comment: How do you distinguish between a user triggered update from any other update? In sql update is an update, mysql cannot tell who or what issued it. It may be better to handle this in the application layer. Having said that, if the non-user issued insert / updates do not ever set column B, but user triggered inserts / updates always do, then using before insert / update triggers you can detect this and set column B's value.

Comment: Well, as phpmyadmin let's me define a standard value upon creation of the row as a hardcoded value, I thought maybe there's a way to point it to another column easily. If not, I just have to solve that on the application level, which is no big deal. Just want to try to learn and understand databases a bit better...

Comment: To repeat what Shadow said, just to make sure you understood it: you used the term "user triggered update". You could have used this intentionally because you want to distinguish between updates explicitly done by users, and those done by the system. Or you could have used it because it sounded nice, and you just meant "any update". The 1st version makes it more complicated (as Shadow elaborated), the 2nd version isn't at all (it is a simple insert trigger, although, depending on your application, it can be better to just set that column manually). You should maybe clarify that point.

Comment: Ok, to clarify, I meant any update that changes the value after the row is initially created.I used the term user triggered because that's would cause an update in my application, but it is any update essentially.

Comment: In that case, you can indeed simply use a "before insert" trigger, see [mysql set field default value to other column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15384429) (exception: using autoincrement values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql set field default value to other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384429/mysql-set-field-default-value-to-other-column)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not allow you to default a value using an expression with other columns.

One solution is an `insert` trigger on the table to set `B` to `A`.  However, if `A` changes, this doesn't keep track -- unless you have an `update` trigger.  But then you don't know when `B` is set manually or not.  Oh, this is hard to keep track of.

You can do something else using a computed column -- assuming that you never want `B` to be set manually to `NULL`.  This looks like:

```
create table t as (
     . . . ,
     a int not null,
     _b int,
     b int generated always as (coalesce(_b, a))
);
```

Then, in your code, you use `b` for querying.  When you want to set the value, you would set the value of `_b`.

Of course, you could extend this to have a boolean flag on whether `a` or `_b` is used for `b`.  However, using `NULL` to distinguish whether a value is set illustrates the idea and is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer by John C in
[MySQL: set field default value to other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384429/mysql-set-field-default-value-to-other-column)

I was able to alter a table setting the default value as the concatenation of two other columns in that table:

```
ALTER TABLE t_table MODIFY IDOne_IDTwo varchar(12) DEFAULT ( concat(IDOne,'-',IDTwo) );
```

Be sure to wrap parentheses around your expressions and leave the literals bare.
MySQL documentation regarding allowing expressions as default values: Explicit [Default Handling as of MySQL 8.0.13](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit).