# How to add MySQL table column with a default value of another column of the existing row

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The current existing table looks like this:

```
id    number    amount    
1     123       30000.00
2     123       15000.00
3     321       45000.00
...   ...       ...
1000  567       75000.00
```

Now i would like add new column `allocated_amount` with the default value of the `amount` column in every existing row.

```
id    number    amount      allocated_amount  
1     123       30000.00    30000.00
2     123       15000.00    15000.00
3     321       45000.00    45000.00
...   ...       ...         ...
1000  567       75000.00    75000.00
```

It is possible? Im using MySQL Workbench GUI.

Comment: This might provide some help, but they talk about using a trigger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377977/mysql-default-value-as-other-fields-value. What rules are used to determine the allocated amount?

Comment: That is true, thanks man

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible as default column. You can write a trigger and do that or add virtual column in Mysql 5.7.

OR

```
alter table Tab1 add allocated_amount int;  -- Add column
update Tab1 set allocated_amount= amount;   -- Set the value
```

Or you could create a Virtual Column:

```
alter table Table1 
add allocated_amount integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (amount) VIRTUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Virtual Column:

```
alter table Table1 
add allocated_amount integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (amount) VIRTUAL;
```

Comment: One answer per person per question please. Its fine to give options in a single answer

Comment: let's delete this answer to not confuse newcomers please ;-)